# Why do mathematicians bother to study the games in descriptive set theory?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

In descriptive set theory, a game (e.g., the [Choquet game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_game) or the [Banach-Mazur game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_game)) is usually played by two players, who take turns selecting some subsets or/and elements of a given set X. At least at first sight, this roundabout game procedure can hinder a direct intuition of the set X.

If we want to study a certain property of some set(s), why not take other approach? Do the games provide any insightful viewpoints that other approaches can't? Why do mathematicians study the games in descriptive set theory?

Comment: I never saw someone studying set theory by using games. So can you give an example?

Comment: @miracle The Choquet Game and the Banach-Mazur Game.

Comment: What is an insightful viewpoint? Are the results of these games not already interesting enough to warrant investigation? Or is your question more about the specific properties that can be determined using the games?

Comment: @Michael thx, could you edit your Post and add this information

Comment: Related: I found it helpful to visualize $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proofs as a two-player game when learning limits.  For example, the addition law of limits would involve the antagonist choosing an $\epsilon$, the protagonist choosing $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, the antagonist choosing $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, and the protagonist choosing $\delta$.

Comment: "At least at first sight, this roundabout game procedure can hinder a direct intuition of the set X." I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain why you think talking about games makes it harder to think about sets?

Comment: @NoahSchweber When considering whether a space\set X has a certain property, we can first consider some examples that share some other properties with X, and use them to help get an intuition of or visualise the space X. Then we continue to figure out to way to solve the original problem. However, in a game, it's hard to know what impact a (certain) move of a player will have on the whole game. It's a bit like in the chess, you hardly know what your move will lead to.

Comment: @Michael I honestly don't get what you're trying to say. "we can first consider some examples that share some other properties with X, and use them to help get an intuition of or visualise the space X" is really vague, and I don't see how thinking about games on $X$ prevents me from also thinking about $X$. And your claim about analyzing the impacts of moves in games just seems false to me; proofs connecting tameness properties and determinacy (e.g. "meager = player $2$ has winning strategy for Banach-Mazur game") seem extreme counterexamples.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't mean thinking about games on X prevents one from also thinking about X. It's just that it doesn't provide convenience to think about the games. If we are not interested in game theory itself, we can do without the games in descriptive set theory.